# WinJS how to make appendTextAsync wait for file available

Tags: file-io, promise, winjs

I have code like this for logging in my WinJS app:

```
function setupFileLog() {
    var logFn = function (message, tag, type) {
        if (!log_file) return; // log_file is global, setup below with a StorageFile object
        Windows.Storage.FileIO.appendTextAsync(log_file, tag + ' ' + type + ': ' + message)
            .done(null, function (error) {
                // I have a breakpoint here to catch the error
                var msg = error.detail.message;
                }
            });
    };

    app_folder.createFolderAsync('logs', Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists)
       .then(function (logfolder) {
           var now = new Date();
           var logfilename = config.device + "_" + now.toDateString() + ".log";
           return logfolder.createFileAsync(logfilename, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists)
       })
       .done(function (file) {
           log_file = file; // save in global var
           WinJS.Utilities.startLog({ tags: "myApp", action: logFn });
       });
}

setupFileLog();

// ...
// do stuff and log things
// ...

WinJS.log && WinJS.log('I did some stuff', 'myApp','info');
WinJS.log && WinJS.log('I got an error: '+error, 'myApp','error');
```

Intermittently, I get an error in my logFn "The process cannot access the file because it is in use by another process" or "Access is denied".  I think that multiple calls to WinJS.log are colliding because of the async nature of the appendText call and trying to get a handle to the log file before the previous logging call is finished writing.

Can I make appendTextAsync wait until the log file is not in use? I can't find any calls to check if the file is busy. I think there is a way to make appendTextAsync act in a synchronous way but I'd like to avoid doing that in all cases since this is just an intermittent case.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for the solution. I did add `return` in front of the `appendTextAsync` call and then it worked great. I also moved the `log_file` variable to a global so I could test whether or not it was already set, in which case I cleared things out first by adding this to the beginning of `setupFileLog()` -- `if (log_file) { WinJS.Utilities.stopLog(); log_file.done(); log_file=null; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a chain of calls that is automatically executed in sequence:

```
function setupFileLog() {
    var log_file = app_folder.createFolderAsync('logs', Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists)
   .then(function (logfolder) {
        var now = new Date();
        var logfilename = config.device + "_" + now.toDateString() + ".log";
        return logfolder.createFileAsync(logfilename, Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.openIfExists)
    });

    WinJS.Utilities.startLog({
        tags: "myApp",
        action: function log_fn(message, tag, type) {
             log_file = log_file.then(function(file) {
                 return Windows.Storage.FileIO.appendTextAsync(file, tag + ' ' + type + ': ' + message)
                 .then(function() {
                     return file;
                 }, function (error) {
                    // I have a breakpoint here to catch the error
                    var msg = error.detail.message;
                    return file; // for further logs, or
                    throw error; // go stop logging
                 });
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Every call to the `log_fn` does chain another `appendTextAsync` call onto the `log_file` promise. The bonus is that calls are already chained when the log file is not yet created, instead of simply dropping log lines.

Comment: I have tried this code but the second time I call WinJS.log and it gets into the `log_fn`, file is undefined. So I can't determine if the file access error I was getting is gone.

Comment: Hm, with `.then(function() { return file; }` the new `log_file` promise should again contain the file. Not sure why it doesn't?

Comment: Wait I think I got it working by changing it to `return Windows.Storage.FileIO.appendTextAsync...` let me make sure with more testing...

Comment: So far so good! No more file access errors, thanks! One more question -- if I call `setupFileLog()` again, to set up a new log file with a different name, subsequent log writes are duplicated in the new file. It's almost like the old promise in `log_file` is chained with the new one. Is there something I should do to clear out the existing log_file promise before creating a new one?

Comment: OMG, of course, thanks! The most basic error when dealing with promises :-/

Comment: I don't know how `WinJS.Utilities.startLog` works, but if the entries are duplicated it sounds as if both `log_fn`s are called. Probably you should solve that. If not, then replacing the `log_file` promise with a rejected one should prevent further log writes to it.